# On an inner product condition between symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, matrix-calculus

Let $A$, $B$ be two square $n\times n$ real matrices and suppose that $B=B^\top$ is positive definite. Denote by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the trace inner product in the space of symmetric matrices, that is $\langle X,Y\rangle:=\mathrm{tr}(X^\top Y)$, for $X,Y$ symmetric matrices.

> **My question:** Suppose that
>   $$
> \langle A+A^\top,\alpha(AB+BA^\top)+\beta B\rangle=0,
> $$
>   for all $\alpha$, $\beta$ real numbers. Does the previous condition implies $A+A^\top=0$?

---

**A simple remark.** If $AB=BA$ then it is easy to see that the answer is affirmative (just pick $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Let me use a notation for the trace product that is much easier to type 
$$X:Y = {\rm tr}(X^TY) = {\rm tr}(XY^T)$$
If $B$ is symmetric, then the term
$$\eqalign{
 C &= AB + (AB)^T = AB + B^TA^T = AB + BA^T \cr
}$$
is symmetric.

Next note that the linear combination of two symmetric matrices, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 S &= \alpha C + \beta B \cr
}$$
is itself symmetric.

So we have this expression
$$\eqalign{
 0 &= (A+A^T):S \cr
 &= A:S + A^T:S \cr
 &= A:S + A:S^T \cr
 &= 2A:S \cr
0 &= A:S \cr
}$$
and that final equality means that $A$ is indeed skew-symmetric.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'm missing the last step: Why does $0=A:S$ imply that $A$ is skew-symmetric?